# How can I to show message from specified clicked spoiler with just CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have some spoilers and I need to display the contents of the spoiler after clicking the corresponding button

```css
.spoiler {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#checker {
    display: none;
}
.toggle {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ecf0f1;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #aaa;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#checker:not(:checked) ~ .spoiler {
    height: 0;
}
#checker:checked ~ .toggle {
    display: none;
}
code.text {
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Here is the problem that when I press a first spoiler, always shows the contents of the first.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checker">
<label for="checker" class="toggle">show spoiler 1</label>
<div class="spoiler">
    <code class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1.</code>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="checker">
<label for="checker" class="toggle">show spoiler 2</label>
<div class="spoiler">
    <code class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2.</code>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="checker">
<label for="checker" class="toggle">show spoiler 3</label>
<div class="spoiler">
    <code class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3.</code>
</div>
```

I think to add an id to each spoiler, but I do not know if CSS supports this.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checker1">
<label for="checker1" class="toggle">show spoiler 1</label>
<div class="spoiler1">
    <code class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1.</code>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="checker2">
<label for="checker2" class="toggle">show spoiler 2</label>
<div class="spoiler2">
    <code class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2.</code>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Only** using css, I think every single one having id might be the only way to go.

```css
.spoiler {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.checker {
    display: none;
}
.toggle {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ecf0f1;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #aaa;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.checker:not(:checked) + .toggle + .spoiler {
    height: 0;
}
.checker:checked + .toggle {
    display: none;
}
code.text {
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checker1" class="checker">
<label for="checker1" class="toggle">show spoiler 1</label>
<div class="spoiler">
    <code class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1.</code>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="checker2" class="checker">
<label for="checker2" class="toggle">show spoiler 2</label>
<div class="spoiler">
    <code class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2.</code>
</div>
```

main modification (css):

`.checker:checked ~ .toggle` to `.checker:checked + .toggle`

`.checker:not(:checked) ~ .spoiler` to `.checker:not(:checked) + .toggle + .spoiler`

Comment: @modInfo if only there were parent selectors or some way to do conditions it would be easier.